# Is there any reason not to just generate a random authentication token?

Tags: php, authentication, hmac

I'm developing a web application, and I'm trying to wrap my head around the best authentication system to use.  Basically, I want the client to send my server a username and password, and I want the server to respond by giving the client a token that can be used in lieu of a password from that point forward.

I've looked into this a little and a recommendation I keep seeing is to use an HMAC with a secret key known only to the server.  I see the benefit of this method, but it still seems to me that this isn't ideal, since as far as I am able to tell it cannot be expired.

I can add extra security by adding the ip address to the string used for creating/verifying the hmac, I believe, but I'm still not sure if this is the best way.

Is there any reason not to just have my authentication token simply be generated with something like openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() and stored in my database along with an ip address and username?  Then I can just send the user that and verify it against what's in the database.  It also allows me to easily expire or log out the user.

Comment: essentially what you're talking about is a session cookie. that is a pseudo-random string that simply represents SOMETHING on the server. e.g. a file with that string as the name, a database record with that string as an ID, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a secret key known only to the server it can be expired any time you want?  Just change the secret key (keeping a history for expiration tracking purposes) and all the old tokens should be invalidated.

If that is the rotue you go, I suggest using a different secret for each user, this allows you to revoke specific user tokens at will.